# PhpStorm add syntax highlight and intellisense for Firebase rules

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, phpstorm, webstorm, firebase-storage

Hello I'm looking for some PhpStorm plugin, that provides syntax highlight and intellissense for Firebase rules?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46600491/what-is-the-name-of-the-language-used-for-cloud-firestore-security-rules

Answer (score 4):

Seems there are no plugins for that; please vote for [IDEA-200507](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-200507) to be notified on any progress with this feature